# Kolmogorov backward equations for Birth-Death

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm trying to solve the Kolmogorov backward equations for a Birth-Death Markov chain with three states. I have 2 equations:

$$P_{00}'(t) = \lambda_0 (P_{10}(t)-P_{00}(t))$$
$$P_{10}'(t) = \mu_1P_{00}(t)$$

do I understand it correctly that the forward equations will give the same results

EDIT
I was able to confirm (numerically) the same results.

I could not find a way to delete this question or close it.